# (Opencart)Не обновляется stylesheet.css в браузере

Tags: opencart

Редактирую stylesheet.css в редакторе потом загружаю через ftp,при просмотре файла в редакторе изменения есть,но в браузерах старые стили.Есть sass файлы ,так для инфы.

Comment: Какие могут быть причины: sass файл перезаписывает ваш stylesheet.css; вы не очистили кэш в браузере; файл не загрузился на сервер.

Comment: А если открыть stylesheet.css по прямой ссылке в браузере. Изменения есть?

Comment: Добрый день. скорее всего хранится кеш, Ctrl + F5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В **opencart 3** используется шаблонизатор **twig** с его родным кешированием. В админку под этот случай выведена кнопка управления кешированием (шестерёнка - см. скриншот). Она даёт возможность управлять кешированием на стадии разработки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]